# Reading Windows 8.1 files from the Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8

I have tried to do these steps: http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Ubuntu

but it didn't work. Then i read [here](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/) that deleting the `hiberfile.sys` will help, but it didn’t also. Instead, when i boot ubuntu, i get a error-message that was a **mount** error.

**How can i fix that and what is the right way to read windows files from ubuntu?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly need to disable "hibernation/fast boot" in windows 8. Here are the steps I can suggest:

- boot into windows.
- open the terminal/cmd.
- run the following command in the windows terminal: powercfg /h off
- reboot windows.
- make sure hiberfil.sys is gone!
- now boot into ubuntu.
- mount the windows partition.

hth!